# About Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

**What is the difference between using:**

```
function random(array){
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)];
}
```

(vs)

```
function random(array){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length);
}
```

Why are we adding *return* **array**[] in front **??**

**I came through *Silly Story Generator* in MDN example** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Silly_story_generator

here's my source code - https://codepen.io/ranjanrnj44/pen/abzNQYg

Comment: For starters, the first one returns an element of the array indexed by `Math.floor(Math.random()*array.length)` (assuming that the calculation provides a valid index), whereas the second one simply provides a value based upon the length of the array and a random number.

Comment: it's the same as the difference between `return 10` and `return array[10]`.

Comment: can't see why you couldn't run both and observe the difference yourself to be honest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first function returns the value of the array at index ran, the second returns the index itself.

There's no difference between what the two functions return, *if* your array is made up of ordinal numbers [0...x]. For example:

`[0,1,2,3,4]`

because `random1()` returns the value of the nth index of the array:

```
array[0] = 0
array[1] = 1
array[2] = 2
array[3] = 3
array[4] = 4
```

If the array is structured in *any other way*, the functions will operate differently. For example, with the array:

### Examples

First:

```
array: [1,2,3,4,5]
funcs:      random1()   random2()
results:    1           0
            2           1
            3           2
            4           3
            5           4
```

Second:

```
array: ["a","b","c","d","e"]
funcs:      random1()   random2()
results:    "a"         0
            "b"         1
            "c"         2
            "d"         3
            "e"         4
```

```js
function random1(array){
    const num = Math.random()*array.length
    const flooredNum = Math.floor(num)
    return array[flooredNum]
}


function random2(array){
    const num = Math.random()*array.length
    return Math.floor(num)
}

let arr = [0,1,2,3,4]

console.log("random1", random1(arr))
console.log("random2", random2(arr))

arr = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

console.log("random1", random1(arr))
console.log("random2", random2(arr))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just returning a Random number between 0 and array.length - 1

```js
function random(array) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
}

console.log(random([50,30,100]));
```

---

This is getting a random element in the Array, by using the random number as [the index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements)

```js
function random(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

console.log(random([50,30,100]));
```

Comment: Thanks, so in order to get 1 particular (number/string part) we are using it right?

Comment: Your use of `random_it` seems fine. However, there's a minor issue in how you're using `random_color(255)`. Because you're using Math.floor, you'll want to input 256 instead of 255, to get a random range of 0 - 255

Comment: Got it, Thanks a lot  for your reply :-)